# Opening another dialog fragment and closing the previous one

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

In my code I have to open another dialog fragment when a textview is clicked, the textView is in the main dialog Fragment

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnclickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v){
     NewDialogFragment.newInstance().show(getChildFragmentManager(),"");
     dismiss(); 
   }
});
```

problem is that, when the textview is clicked in the main dialog fragment gets `dismiss()` but new DialogFragment doesn't open,

expected result is that the main dialogFrament should `dismiss()` and the `NewDialogFragment()` should appear

Thanks

Comment: Please share your code properly...

Comment: Can you share the full `NewDialogFragment` as well as the dialog fragment where you are calling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `getChildFragmentManager()` to just `getParentFragmentManager()`.

The reason for doing this is because you want the `FragmentManager` of the `Activity`, not of the `DialogFragment` you're about to dismiss. Else, you'll give the `FragmentManager` of the dialog and then you dismiss it which will dismiss the dialog you just attached.

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnclickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v){
     NewDialogFragment.newInstance().show(getParentFragmentManager(),"");
     dismiss(); 
   }
});
```

Comment: You may want to consider using getParentFragmentManager() instead

Comment: Thanks. Have updated answer. FYI, `getParentFragmentManager()` is the same as calling `getFragmentManager()` but now the latter is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(s->{
NewDialogFragment.newInstance().dismiss()
NewDialogFragment.newInstance().show(getChildFragmentManager(),"");
});
```

Comment: same result, didn't work, anything else that i can try, please suggest

Comment: how you opened first fragment?

Comment: same way with newInstance().show(getChildFragmentManager(),""), but in a fragment, now i have to open new dialog fragment from a dialog fragment

Comment: Then you have to call NewDialogFragment.newInstance().dismiss() check updated answer.

Comment: It crashed, cannot dismiss the fragment before showing it.

Comment: are you using the same dialog fragment NewDialogFragment for first dialog?

Comment: I have updated my question a bit,
first dialog fragment is the main Dialog fragment

Comment: then get the instance of that dialog fragment and dismiss it

Comment: I tried this solution didn't work , but it didn't crash this time.